# List remove duplicates using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and i'm trying to remove duplicates from a simple list by using list comprehension (without using sets).

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

i can do it by doing this:

```
z=[]
for x in a:
   if(z.count(x)==0):
     z.append(x)
```

but with using list comprehension i don't know why it doesn't work:

```
z=[]
z=[x for x in a if z.count(x)==0]
```

what's the error there ?

Comment: Because your counter can't have `0` entries? If it exists in the list, it must, at least, have a count of `1`

Comment: @roganjosh This part makes sense. See the non-list comprehension version

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582741/4932316) out

Comment: `z` is not defined within the scope of the list.

Comment: One solution using list comprehension is `z = [i for n, i in enumerate(a) if i not in a[:n]]` as per the link I posted above

Comment: I've found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067330/9727794). Thank you guys for everything